# How to calculate max with condition in Numbers?

Tags: numbers

How can I calculate max with condition in Numbers?

In other words, I want something like `maxifs`, which operates max operation instead of sum operation for `sumifs`.

Comment: The question is perfectly on-topic on AskDifferent. Any potential answerers shouldn't let themselves get confused by the SQL-like query above which as far as I understand only serves to illustrate the expected result.

Comment: @patrix yes, you are correct, thank you for adding explanation. I used SQL only to explain expected result in other terms than the question itself.

Comment: As Numbers does not support (yet) Array functions, this is a tricky one.  Even for [Excel](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2013/11/19/using-max-if-with-multiple-criteria/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers version 3 on Mac and the equivalent web app/ios app do not have that level of abstraction, but on a Mac, Numbers is fairly scriptable in powerful ways.

I would probably dump the data into a SQLite database if your comment means you are familiar with that. This is documented at the wonderful OS X Automation site.

- https://iworkautomation.com/numbers/sqlite-make.html

You could also program the logic you wanted in Applescript or possible the new javascript bridge for AppleScript on later OS X versions. Here is an example of complicated logic used to format cells. You could likely adapt that to process the data and then write the results to a new table.

- https://iworkautomation.com/numbers/examples-highlight-intersection.html

It's not the same, but it would let you use numbers and not Excel for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Mac Numbers does now have a `MAXIFS` function. But, it depends on exactly what you want to do with it. If you could edit your question to add an example, I could expand this answer to address how to use `MAXIFS` in Numbers for that example.

I use it in a column where vertically there are two types of data: a number for order from 1 to 4 and an associated mass which is greater than 40, so:

```
MAXIFS(Col Range for max, Col Range for test 1, test 1, Col Range for test 2, test 2, ... more tests as required)
```

All columns have to be the same length. It takes the maximum value in the subset of the max range of all those values horizontally next to the values in the test ranges that pass their tests.

However, if want a passive value, ie, not one that is maximised, such as a date, that is associated with the maxes calculated in the test ranges, you have to use maxifs to find the maximum value and then use that as an argument to `XLOOKUP`.